# How do I resolve an expired x509 certificate issue while installing STS4 from Eclipse Marketplace?

Tags: x509certificate, eclipse-marketplace, spring-tools-4

I've just downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0) Build id: 20220908-1902 and fired up the Marketplace client to install Spring Tools 4 (4.16.0.RELEASE).

Edit: I should add that I used the same workspace as the previous version and chose to convert it for the latest version when prompted

I clicked "Install" and kept only the required features and then clicked "Confirm" and accepted the license agreements, then clicked "Finish".

While waiting for it to download and install, a "Trust" dialog popped up saying the two items have expired. One is "Pivotal R&D" and the other is "Pivotal ", they expired back in 2020 and 2018, respectively.

A Google search did not turn up similar issues reported by anyone. I'm not behind any firewall, proxy, or VPN. I would like to know how to proceed with the install without having to trust these expired certificates.
[Dialog showing expired certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY5Tv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed an issue for this here: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/852 - we basically need to update the signing information for those pre-built third-party bundles that we include in the Spring Tools 4 distribution builds.

In the meantime, unfortunately you need to trust the expired certificate to get the bundles installed.

Comment: Thank you, as long as it's a known issue it's good enough for me.